# Getting started with e-commerce sites on WordPress

Tags: e-commerce

Are there any good resources for building an e-commerce storefront? I am aware of the e-commerce plugins available but I am mainly interested in learning practices and techniques for the design and development of an e-commerce site for someone who has never built one before.

Obviously, nothing is stopping me from just trying, but figured I would ask if there are good resources out there to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larry Ullman's book [PHP 6 and MySQL 5 for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide](http://www.larryullman.com/books/php-6-and-mysql-5-for-dynamic-web-sites-visual-quickpro-guide-3rd-edition/) has an excellent chapter on building an e-Commerce website. It has nothing to do with WordPress, but I found it to be an excellent introduction to the very basic e-Commerce concepts way back when I read it. I think it would be a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like he also has a book "Effortless E-Commerce with PHP and MySQL".

Comment: +1 to you! He's a great writer and he's written a ton of books, but that one has never come on my radar. Thanks for the info!

Comment: any issues with learning PHP 6 while everything is still PHP 5?

Comment: I actually read the PHP5 version of the book, which I think is still very relevant. I had a friend buy the PHP6 book, and if memory serves, Ullman did a good job pointing out what is PHP6 only. Perhaps, the better way to go would be to buy the most up-to-date PHP5 version of the book (which I believe is the 2nd edition). You'd probably be able to get a great deal on a used copy. Excellent question btw!